# Use Root object as a function in NonlinearModelFit or similar

Tags: equation-solving, fitting, linear-algebra

I have a matrix and its eigenvalues are returned by Mathematica as a Root Object.

```
m = (154982971 \[Pi])/120000000000000000000000000
kx=(57*2*Pi*1000)^2*m;
ky = (63*2*Pi*1000)^2*m;
shift =41*lambda;
kz = (0.95*Abs[Cos[shift*Pi/(1.55*10^-6)]]*2.76748*NA*\[Sqrt](-((\[Sqrt](1+1.05166*10^11*shift^2)*(-3.04068*10^-53-1.59889*10^-41*shift^2-3.36298*10^-30*shift^4-3.53672*10^-19*shift^6-1.85972*10^-8*shift^8-3.91159*10^2*shift^10+2.5281*10^-3*shift^12-4.59177*10^17*shift^16)+\[Sqrt](r)*(-1.90651*10^-50-1.00122*10^-38*shift^2-2.10421*10^-27*shift^4-2.21222*10^-16*shift^6-1.16344*10^-5*shift^8-2.44865*10^5*shift^10-3.19614*10^1*shift^12-6.97912*10^11*shift^14+1.05794*10^21*shift^16+8.07794*10^30*shift^18-5.55112*10^41*shift^20)+r*\[Sqrt](1+1.05166*10^11*shift^2)*(-3.04068*10^-53+3.19777*10^-42*shift^2+1.68149*10^-30*shift^4+1.06101*10^-19*shift^6+3.95332*10^-24*shift^8+4.52784*10^-14*shift^10+1.16682*10^-3*shift^12-5.34553*10^7*shift^14))/((9.50876*10^-12+1.*shift^2)^5*\[Sqrt](1+1.05166*10^11*shift^2))))*2*Pi*1000)^2*m;
kappaXY = 7*10^-8;
kappaXZ = 0.7*(63/57)*10^-8;
kappaYZ = 0.7*1*10^-8;
Clear[kappaXY]
A = 1/m*{{0, 0, 0, -kx - kappaXY - kappaXZ, kappaXY, kappaXZ}, {0, 0, 
     0, kappaXY, -ky - kappaXY - kappaYZ, kappaYZ}, {0, 0, 
     0, +kappaXZ, +kappaYZ, -kz - kappaXZ - kappaYZ}, {m, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0}, {0, m, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, m, 0, 0, 0}};
Eigenvalues[A]
```

gives among others

```
0.010266 Root[
  2.80529*10^44 + 9.67644*10^50 kappaXY + 6.59487*10^45 Sqrt[r] + 
    2.27466*10^52 kappaXY Sqrt[r] - 3.58672*10^39 r - 
    1.23711*10^46 kappaXY r + (2.27095*10^30 + 
       7.11236*10^36 kappaXY + 9.72679*10^30 Sqrt[r] + 
       1.66138*10^37 kappaXY Sqrt[r] - 5.29007*10^24 r - 
       9.03569*10^30 kappaXY r) #1^2 + (2.88981*10^15 + 
       4.6771*10^21 kappaXY + 3.55217*10^15 Sqrt[r] - 
       1.9319*10^9 r) #1^4 + #1^6 &, 1]
```

I want to fit the imaginary part of this expression to data with kappaXY as a parameter and r the variable.
Is there any way to do so?
If I just use the expression as it is I get the error message

> Root::npoly: 9.67644*10^50+2.27466*10^52 Sqrt[#1]-1.23711*10^46 #1+(7.11236*10^36+1.66138*10^37 Sqrt[#1]-9.0357*10^30 #1) #1^2+(4.6771*10^21+3.55217*10^15 Sqrt[#1]-1.9319*10^9 #1) #1^4+#1^6 is not a polynomial in #1.

Somehow #1 appeared as a Sqrt now.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You may find it useful to evaluate `Eigenvalues[A} // ToRadicals`, which will express the eigenvalues without using `Root`.  In order to provide detailed help, people here will want to have values of $m, k_x, k_y, k_z$ so that we can duplicate your results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited such that the constants are included. I think ```// ToRadicals ``` does not work for higher order Polynomials no?

Comment: (1) I get `lambda` as a parameter, too. Should it have a value? (2) Something like `ev1[kappa_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] = Root[..]` might work but without runnable code, it's inconvenient to test & tweak. (3) `Root` objects are not in general continuous functions of parameters. It might or might not be a problem.

Comment: If you give numeric definitions to `kappaXY`, `lambda`, `NA`, and `r`, `Eigenvalues` yields a numeric result. If you're fitting to data, thats what you want, not a huge symbolic expression.

Comment: Difficult to comment without full code to replicate the issue. One possibility would be to impose the polynomial constraint (that satisfies the characteristic polynomial for that matrix), using the appropriate form of `NonlinearModelFit`. Also keep in mind that a rapidly varying cosine where the factor is of the order 10^8 will be difficult to get correct at machine precision (since this function will basically be working with error terms on the order of half of machine precision). So this might require some nondefault settings.